# Ellipsis added to url when copying on windows

Tags: windows

I have no clue why, and can't reproduce it, but some times, when I copy urls, it pastes "http://some..." instead of "http://someLongUrlLink.com". I'm on windows 10 latest updates (anniv).

Comment: Does it happen completely randomly, or just in some programs or on some websites?

Comment: Correction:Maybe it has something to do with Skype, I think I've oknly seen it there. Original: Even though I doubt it's random, I can't say otherwise (I don't know what causes it) A friend of mine has the same issue, for example on this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJgC9LEBTuQ&oref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmJgC9LEBTuQ&has_verified=1